# PHP - replacing or matching \r\n in a string?

Tags: php, regex, line-breaks

I have a string, it looks like this:

```
PS-B 08 m.Gear\r\n125cm silver
```

I am trying to replace the \r\n with something else, but all my tries failed so far. I tried `[\r\n]`, I tried . and I tried the s modifier, none of them worked. How can I replace or match a string with `\r\n` properly?

Thanks!

Comment: additional tip: from your description it seems like you tried a regex function - in regex \ has special functions, so you should escape it \\r\\n . And: for a simple replace, use str_replace (see the answers), it is less resource demanding

Comment: *"I tried ..."* if you tried something that didn't work, post the code. Otherwise it didn't happen and you're simply asking other people to write code for you for free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
$str = 'PS-B 08 m.Gear\r\n125cm silver';
$newStr = str_replace('\r\n', '######', $str);
echo $newStr;
```

**Result:**

```
PS-B 08 m.Gear######125cm silver
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `"\r\n"`, then:

```
$str = str_replace("\r\n", $something, $your_str);
```

Comment: Isn't `\r\n` the newline for windows? or It's real `\r\n`, then you don't need `"`, use `'` instead.